# パケット解析ツールの違いが分からない。

Tags: network, tcp, wireshark, tcpdump

パケットを解析するツールでtcpdump, wireshark, ここでプロキシサーバを立てるか立てないかで別れてそう。Charles proxy, mitmproxyの違いがよく分からないです。
教えて頂けないでしょうか。

Comment: ツールは目的で使い分けるものなので＊＊＊がしたいから○○○ツールを使う、んです。違いだけ聞いてもあまり役に立たなさそう。

Comment: ツールの特徴は各ツールのマニュアル等に記載されているはずなので、まずはそれらを確認するのが先だと思います。それで足りなければ使い方の紹介記事などを辿っていくことになるでしょう。例として "wireshark tcpdump" で検索するだけでも、次のような記事が見つかります。https://knowledge.sakura.ad.jp/6311/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

見ることのできるレイヤがことなります。TCPやIP、Ethernetの生データをCharles proxy, mitmproxyなんかのHTTPを見るツールで見ることはできません。
あと当然ですがプロトコルに特化したツールはレイヤが同じでも他のプロトコルには何の役にも立ちません。

Wiresharkは高機能なので上位のレイヤもある程度解析して見やすくしてくれますが、そっちに特化したツールと比べるとできることは限られますし、HTTPが見たいだけなのに余計なデータも表示されるのは邪魔です。ただし生データを取ってみるので、アプリケーション側に手を加える必要はありません。HTTPはProxyの仕組みがあるのでいいのですがこれは例外的に楽な例です。

tcpdumpもある程度はデコードして表示してくれますがまぁおまけ程度です。ただし標準で入ってるのは大きなメリットです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。MitmProxyでは見れない通信があるのですか？wiresharkではそのような事なく全ての通信が表示されると言う事でしょうか？